# Error al usar GCC con Sublime Text 3

Tags: c, windows10, gcc

Ya instalé MinGW y lo agregué al PATH, pero al dar CTRL+B en Sublime Text, me da la siguiente salida:

`` C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status [Finished in 0.9s] ``

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Soluciones
1: Si lo estas instalando desde descargas u otra carpeta, copia la carpeta del programa a program files y agrega esa ruta al path, por ejemplo,
C:/Program Files/carpeta_del_archivo/carpeta_del_ejecutable;

Después reinicia.